# Find size of glm::vec3 array

Tags: c++, arrays, glm-math

I have this `glm::vec3` array and I would like to know the size of the array:

```cpp
glm::vec3 cubePositions[] = {
        glm::vec3(0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f),
        glm::vec3(2.0f,  5.0f, -15.0f),
        glm::vec3(-1.5f, -2.2f, -2.5f),
        glm::vec3(-3.8f, -2.0f, -12.3f),
        glm::vec3(2.4f, -0.4f, -3.5f),
        glm::vec3(-1.7f,  3.0f, -7.5f),
        glm::vec3(1.3f, -2.0f, -2.5f),
        glm::vec3(1.5f,  2.0f, -2.5f),
        glm::vec3(1.5f,  0.2f, -1.5f),
        glm::vec3(-1.3f,  1.0f, -1.5f)
    };
```

So far the size is 10 but is there a way to find that in code?

I have tried `cubePositions->length()` but it only gives me the value 3.

I have tried `glm::length(cubePositions)` but it doesn't seem like thats how you use the `glm::length` function. This way gives an error.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cubePositions` is a C style array. It decays to a pointer to `glm::vec3`. See here about array to pointer decay: [What is array to pointer decay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay).

Therefore when you use `cubePositions->length()` it's equivalent to using `cubePositions[0].length()`, which returns the glm length of the first element (i.e. 3 because it's a `vec3`).

To get the number of elements in the array in this case you can use:

```
auto num_elements = sizeof(cubePositions) / sizeof(cubePositions[0]);
```

Note: this will work only in the scope where `cubePositions` is defined because only there the real size of the array is known. It will no longer work e.g. if you pass `cubePositions` to another function, because then the array will decay to a pointer and will "loose" it's sizeof.

**However** - this is not the recomended way to do it in C++.
It is better to use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for a dynamic size array.
It has a method: [`size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) to retrieve the number of elements:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<glm::vec3> cubePositions = {
    glm::vec3(0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f),
    glm::vec3(2.0f,  5.0f, -15.0f),
    glm::vec3(-1.5f, -2.2f, -2.5f),
    glm::vec3(-3.8f, -2.0f, -12.3f),
    glm::vec3(2.4f, -0.4f, -3.5f),
    glm::vec3(-1.7f,  3.0f, -7.5f),
    glm::vec3(1.3f, -2.0f, -2.5f),
    glm::vec3(1.5f,  2.0f, -2.5f),
    glm::vec3(1.5f,  0.2f, -1.5f),
    glm::vec3(-1.3f,  1.0f, -1.5f)
};

auto num_elements = cubePositions.size();
```

**Note:** if your array has a fixed size (known at compile time), you can also use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). It also has a [`size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/size) method, although in this case it is not as useful, as the size cannot change dynamically and is actually one of the template parameters.

---

**Update:**:
As @HolyBlackCat commented [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72665933/find-size-of-glmvec3-array/72666564?noredirect=1#comment128362875_72666564), it is better to use [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) to get the number of elements in an old C array:

```
auto num_elements = std::size(cubePositions);
```

It will not compile if you pass a decayed pointer rather than a real array. Just keep in mind that as I wrote above you'd better avoid old C arrays if you can.

Comment: Prefer `std::size(...)` for getting plain array size. It can't be mistakenly applied to a pointer.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - good point, updated my answer.